# This code looks like, groovy will result in bad performance? Is it so?

Tags: groovy

I have been reading Groovy for a month or so. Recently i have came across the following code:

```
class MyBean implements Serializable {
    def untyped
    String typed
    def item1, item2
    def assigned = 'default value'
}
```

And when I do this :

```
def bean = new MyBean()
assert 'default value' == bean.getAssigned()
```

However the above code makes GroovyBeans very very impressive, but still my question is this:
Even though we haven't created the getter function(`getAssigned()`), groovy does for us. So is that groovy produce this for all class's even though we are not intended to work in **GRoovyBeans**? This means that for all class's it creates the setter and getter, even though we wont want? Is this is not the performance issue? Or else my view is worng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a method to a class won't cause a performance issue, as it doesn't have to be called.

If you want direct access to the property, you can use the [Java field operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-Javafield%28.@%29):

```
bean.@assigned
```

Comment: no the thing is groovy have to look for users defined method and it have to replace the methods that have generated automatically, this is an performance issue right?because it take so many steps right?

Comment: This is really unnecessary for performance.  Java is smart enough to inline simple getters, especially if you mark them "final", and yet this makes everything more annoying because the designer of the class would expect his getter to be called.  Please don't program for performance until you really identify a need to (until your code is noticed to be running too slow).  This isn't a comment to tim, just a general comment to anyone considering something like this for performance--in fact there is a good chance it will run slower.